# How to speed up switching pages in a PDF?

Tags: pdf, troubleshooting

How can you speed up flipping between pages in a PDF (currently using ezPDF on a Nexus 7)?

What's the function that determines how fast a PDF can flip pages between? I thought it would be a function of PDF size, however, some smaller-sized PDFs flip between pages faster than some larger PDFs.

By understanding the "function", I hope to convert/refine my PDFs so I can flip between pages faster.

I love reading on my tablet (Nexus 7), but the main area it lacks in (when compared with physical books) is the ability to quickly flip back and forth between pages. It seems most pages need about 2-4 seconds to "set" before moving onto the next page.

Comment: That will very much depend on a) the size of the PDF file, and b) the complexity of the PDF structure. The latter includes whether and how many images there are, and if multiple fonts and different formatting is used. So basically, a small PDF with no images, no special fonts, and only few formattings will probably load much faster and be able to switch between pages much quicker than a huge PDF file with many images, fonts, and a lot of special formatting. But there's nothing Android-specific to this.

Comment: I use the Adobe app which is pretty slow even on a nexus 10. It's more bearable in continuous mode rather than page flipping, especially in portrait mode.